# Disable keyboard popup on select field entry -- ios

Tags: user-experience

When a registrant clicks on our event fee block with field type "select", the keyboard pops up and can block the selection field (on mobile). Is there a way to keep the keyboard for activating on the drop down field -or- activate the select options at the bottom of the page (verses the keyboard)? I've used radio boxes to avoid but prefer the select field type when you have more choices in the field.